# Back button not working laravel ajax crud

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, crud

I am trying to go to previous page but it isn't working and somehow giving me `"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into 'students' ('name', 'email', 'contact', 'course', 'updated_at','created_at') values (?, ?, ?, ?, 2023-07-12 08:59:56, 2023-07-12 08:59:56))"` this error

create.blade

```
<div class="div2">

    <form method="post" name="form" class="create_form" action="{{ route('students.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
        Email <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
        Contact <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"><br><br>
        Course <input type="text" name="course" id="course"><br><br>

        <button type="submit" class="save_create">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" class="back_create" formaction="{{ route('students.index') }}">Back</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ajax submit and back button code block

```
$(document).on('submit', '.create_form', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('students.store') }}",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      window.location.href = ("{{ route('students.index') }}");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Errors :", error);
    }
  });
});

// Back button clicked on create page
$(".back_create").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{ route('students.index') }}",
    success: function(response) {
      window.location.href = ("{{ route('students.index') }}");
    }
  });
});
```

Route is full controller:

> Route::resource('/students',StudentController::class);

I tried to put the url using

> $(this).attr('formaction')

also but then the save button won't work.

Comment: Why not simply use `<a href="{{ route('students.index') }}"...</a>` to go to that page? Do you need to submit the values to the previous page? Why use AJAX to go back to the previous page?

Comment: if your `back_create` button should not trigger your form submit, then change the type from submit to button

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen then how will the button will perform action ?

Comment: I edited my question with error pls check

Comment: @PranavSompura What action do you want it to perform? the submit or the click event?

Comment: Using AJAX to go back to a previous page seems overkill and useless to me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should change

```
<button type="submit" class="back_create" formaction="{{ route('students.index') }}">Back</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="back_create" data-formaction="{{ route('students.index') }}">Back</button>
```

Because of type of button is `submit` will submit form instead
and put this block

```
// Back button clicked on create page
$(".back_create").on("click",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{ route('students.index') }}",
        success: function (response) {
             window.location.href = ("{{ route('students.index') }}");
        }
   });
});
```

to the outside `$(document).on('submit')...`

Comment: The click event is outside the submit, it was just badly formatted.

Comment: `formaction` isn't valid for `type="button"` buttons

Comment: Also `event.preventDefault();` will already stop the form from submitting.

Comment: `type="button"` doesn't even submit a form

Comment: @brombeer , button back not button save

Comment: Yes, the back button, which is `type="button"` and doesn't have a default behaviour. So preventing the default behaviour makes no sense, as using AJAX to change to a page makes no sense, you'd make two requests to that page